# How to Build a site widget/module for Google Place's "Reviews by Google Users"

Tags: php, html, google-maps

Is it possible to build a widget/module that would be placed on a website that would allow a site's visitor to post a review to Google Place's "Reviews by Google Users".

If it is possible, could someone give me some practical steps to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't think they provide that API yet. They do have a check in API from Latitude that may extend to include this.

Comment: I'm guessing you could use a google-maps widget centered on your business, that should show the 'reviews' in the text-bubble. But that might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want an API huh? Like Mike said, I don't believe they offer (or will soon) an API like that.
However, that doesn't mean that you can't corral your customers into leaving reviews while on your site.

Two suggestions come to mind, although I'm sure there are other ways to tackle this issue.

1) Why don't you simply create a button which links back to your places page. If you really want to make the directions explicit, you could have a whole dedicated sub-page on how to leave a review. I understand how the better you direct a user to the call to action, the more likely they are to convert (in this case, leave a review) The URL structure you'd want to use is as follows

`http://maps.google.com/maps/place?hl=en&georestrict=input_srcid:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX#pp-reviews` (the XXX's are just placeholders for your business listing's id).

The #pp-reviews appended at the end of the URL will point users directly to the review section. You can't really be more direct than that.

2) You could potentially embed an iframe which contains the pertinent review information, although this option won't be universally supported. To get around that, just include the link within the iframe in the event that the iframe cannot be displayed:

```
<iframe width="500" height="150" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/place?hl=en&georestrict=input_srcid:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX#pp-reviews" frameborder="1">
click here to <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/place?hl=en&georestrict=input_srcid:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX#pp-reviews">leave a review!</a>.
</iframe>
```

Hope this helps!